# Installing 125a sub panel off 200a outside panel with 150a breaker that powers house panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, installation

My electric meter is on a pole with a breaker panel under it. The panel is 200a with a 200a main breaker and a 150a breaker in the outside panel that feeds the 200a panel in my house. I'm planning to build a small shop about 90ft from the pole and I want to install a 125a panel in the shop.

Would it be easier to splice the lines that go from the meter to the 200a outside panel or splice off the 200a main breaker in the panel? Or is there an easier way?

In the 125a panel for the shop I plan to have a 50a breaker for my TIG welder, a 40a for my mig welder, a 20a for the outlets, and a 10a for overhead lights. I know this will almost max out a 125a panel but I don't plan to need to add anything more as I only plan to do small projects in this shop and larger projects in my other shop.

Picture is of outside panel, 10a breaker is for outside outlet for pool.

[image: MIG welder plate info]

[image: Panel in question]
(click to enlarge image)

Comment: Really to  know how much capacity you have for the shop you would need a proper Load Calculation for the house. Assuming you have capacity the you don't need 40A + 50A for the two welders if they won't be used at the same time, only capacity for the larger. For pricing your target should be a 90A breaker in this outside panel feeding #2 aluminum "mobile home feeder" to the shop. A panel in the shop with a main breaker sized 90A or larger would work fine for distributing loads.

Comment: The 10 you see on the breaker is 10,000 amp interrupting capacity, the short circuit amperage that the breaker is designed to be able  to safely stop. There should be another number someplace on the breaker.

Comment: Well, the line to the shop needs to be protected by a breaker.  Call it a 120A feeder and use a 125A breaker with 1/0 aluminum feeder. (which works just fine for heavy feeders).  You only need to worry about the loads that will be running *at the same time*. The amp rating of the subpanel doesn't matter, but get PLENTY of breaker spaces. They're cheap and rather useful in a shop where you're using 240V a lot.

Comment: Can you get us photos of the nameplates on your welders please?

Comment: I added a pic of the plate on MIG welder. I just ordered the TIG and won't have it till tomorrow but it's 225 amp 110/220 dual voltage. As for the 10k amp breaker....... I don't have an excuse as to why I stupidity looked at that number and not the number on the toggle. Which is 20. And I will figure out the load calculation tonight and get back to you on that